# Clojure Simplification

Tags: clojure

Is there a shorter way of writing:

```
(apply f
  (cons a
    (cons b
      (cons c d))))
```

?

Thanks!

(I'm writing some helper functions that call other functions and this "pattern" seems up to show up alot.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
(apply f a b c d)
```

Note that `d` should be a `seq` in both cases.

Comment: In case the `apply` part is not there, `list*` is also interesting: `(list* a b c d)` instead of `(cons a (cons b (cons c d)))`.